# How to interpret tangent vectors on a manifold as derivations?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-algebra

We have such a definition:

---

Given an algebra $A$ over the field $K$, and $M$ is an $A$-bimodule.
Derivation is a linear map:
$$D:A \to M$$
That satisfies: $D(a*b)=D(a)\bullet b + a\bullet D(b)$
(With respect to given operations)

---

Then we define tangent vector $X$ on manifold $M$ at point $p$ as a map:
$$X:C^{\infty}(M)\to \mathbb{R}$$
(Where $C^{\infty}(M)$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of smooth functions on M)

**Question:** Implication that tanget vector is a derivation is correct, if $\mathbb{R}$ is a $C^{\infty}(M)$-bimodule.
But how do we see that? Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field $\Rightarrow$ ring $\Rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$-$\mathbb{R}$-bimodule over itself. But what about algebra of smooth functions?

Comment: A tangent vector is a sometimes called a "derivation at a point", but it's not a derivation in the sense of your first definition. Rather, a *vector field* on $M$ can be identified with a derivation of the algebra $C^\infty(M)$ in the sense of your first definition.

Comment: @AlexProvost What's the precise definition of "derivation at a point" then? I understand that vector field can be thought as: $V: C^{\infty}(M) \to C^{\infty}(M)$ (derivation) or $V: M \to TM$. So we think that "pointwise" this derivation is a tangent vector. But that is just handwaving. Then tangent vector IS NOT derivation at all in a strict sense of a notion.

Comment: A derivation at a point is a linear map $C^\infty_p \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the Leibniz rule. Some authors do *define* a tangent vector like this. (The data of such a derivation at a point is equivalent to the data of a tangent vector at $p$ using any other definition.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can interpret a tangent vector at $p \in M$ as a derivation in your sense. A tangent vector at $p \in M$ is a map $v \colon C^{\infty}(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is $\mathbb{R}$-linear and satisfies

$$ v(fg) = f(p)v(g) + v(f)g(p). $$

If you consider $\mathbb{R}$ as $C^{\infty}(M)$-bimodule by the structure maps

$$ f \bullet x = f(p) \cdot x, \,\,\, x \bullet g = g(p) \cdot x $$

where $\cdot$ is the regular multiplication of real numbers then the equation above becomes

$$ v(fg) = f \bullet v(g) + v(f) \bullet g. $$

In more fancy terms, you have the evaluation homomorphism $\operatorname{ev}_p \colon C^{\infty}(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is a bimodule over itself so by pulling back using $\operatorname{ev}_p$ we give $\mathbb{R}$ a bimodule structure over $C^{\infty}(M)$.

Comment: Great! Thank you, I'll have to think about this.

Comment: Isn't a tangent vector a map $C^\infty_p(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ and not $C^\infty_p(M) \to C^\infty_p(M)$?

Comment: @AlexProvost: Arg, of course you're right so one still has to consider a bimodule structure. I'll edit this part out.